# How can I change the background color of scriptlets in Netbeans?

Tags: colors, netbeans

When editing JSPs in Netbeans, the scriptlets and JavaScript sections are both highlighted the same color, which is a little visually confusing. Is there any way to modify the color scheme so that scriptlets have one background color and JavaScript sections have a different color?

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using Netbeans 7.2, and I've looked through Options->Fonts & Colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change jsp *scriptlet* tag background color by

Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Select language JSP -> JSP Scriplet tag -> Change the background Color

and for *javascript*

Select Language HTML ->Javascript Embedded in HTML -> Change the background Color

Comment: Awesome, it looks like Netbeans 8 added this functionality.